# SQL FOR XML - data as Elements with Attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am using a sql statement to create and xml output and I need to set the attribute currencyID="EUR" to show like this

[image]

My current output shows like this

[image]

My sql selection is like this

```
(Select 
LineTotalAmount,
TaxTotalAmount,
DuePayableAmount
FOR xml path('ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementMonetarySummation),TYPE),
```

Is this possible to write within the sql statement in sql server?

Comment: That *is* a SQL Statement (although malformed). What is the problem here exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the attribute and the value separately

```
Select 
    'EUR' as 'LineTotalAmount/@currencyID'
    LineTotalAmount,
```